# updated ubuntu repositories on bash on ubuntu on windows

Tags: apt, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I currently have a windows machine that I use as a test environment for Ubuntu via the bash shell in the anniversary update, and virtual machines. It has come to my attention recently that the repositories for things in apt-get for the bash on Ubuntu on Windows do not work. Does anyone here have any idea where to find new repositories for /etc/apt/sources.list on this system?

Thanks!

Comment: What repositories do you currently have?

Comment: archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted universe multiverse, same thing twice but instead of trusty they have trusty-updates and trusty-backports, and also the repository security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security man restricted universe multiverse

Answer (score 0):

The WSL uses the same binaries used by Ubuntu. You can use the same repositories.

---

Currently (October 2017), WSL runs Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. If you have an older version, you can upgrade your distribution using `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` includes the same repositories for ubuntu:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```